# Proving nonsingularity of a sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this study question but I'm not sure how to proceed.  The question is as follows.  If \begin{equation}\frac{||B||_2}{||A||_2}<\frac{1}{\kappa_2(A)}\end{equation} with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ nonsingular and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ show that $A+B$ is nonsingular.  By the inequality and definition of the 2 condition number I get \begin{equation}{||B||_2}<\sigma_n\end{equation} where $\sigma_n$ is the smallest singular value of $A$.  But I'm not sure how, if at all, that's useful.  I also don't see how assuming $A+B$ is singular could be useful.

Comment: What is $\kappa_2(A)$?

Comment: The condition number of $A$, it is defined as \begin{equation}\kappa_2(A)=||A||_2||A^{-1}||_2.\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By rewriting the given inequality in terms of norms, one esily obtains $$\|A^{-1}B\|\le \|A^{-1}\|\|B\|<1,$$
which, combined with obvious

$$A+B = A(I+A^{-1}B),$$
allows to conclude using the convergence of the [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).

**Adding details**

The Neumann theorem says that if the series $$\sum_{k\ge 0}T^k$$ converges in operator norm, then the operator $(I-T)$ is invertible and $$(I-T)^{-1}=\sum_{k\ge 0}T^k.$$
We apply this theorem to the operator $(-A^{-1}B)$. We know that $\|-A^{-1}B\|<1$, hence the series
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\|-A^{-1}B\|^k$$ converges, i.e. the series
$$\sum_{k\ge 0}(-A^{-1}B)^k$$ converges in operator norm; thus, the operator $I+A^{-1}B$ is invertible.

Now we write $$(A+B)^{-1} = (A(I+A^{-1}B))^{-1}= (I+A^{-1}B )^{-1} A ^{-1}.$$ Both factors here are well-defined, hence the operator $(A+B)$ is indeed invertible.

Comment: Okay, I think so.  Using this result and applying the 2-norm we'll get that $||A+B||_2<1$ so $\rho(A+B)<1$(where $\rho(A+B)$ is the spectrum of $A+B$) which means $A+B$ must be nonsingular?

Comment: @Dave No, not even close. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

The condition implies $\|B\|<1/\|A^{-1}\|$ and then $\|BA^{-1}\|\leq\|B\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\|<1$. So the series $I-BA^{-1}+(BA^{-1})^2-(BA^{-1})^3+\dotsb$ converges (treated as linear operators from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$), which is actually $(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}$. Then $A+B=A(I+BA^{-1})$ is also invertible.

Answer (score 0):

A proof without the use of Neumann series by contradiction:

If $A+B$ is singular, then there is a nonzero $x$ such that $Ax=-Bx$ and hence $x=-A^{-1}Bx$ due to the nonsingularity of $A$. Hence
$$
\|x\|_2 = \|A^{-1}Bx\|_2 \leq \|A^{-1}\|_2\|B\|_2\|x\|_2
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
1\leq\|A^{-1}\|_2\|B\|_2
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\frac{1}{\kappa_2(A)}\leq\frac{\|B\|_2}{\|A\|_2}
$$